Как растянуть объект на всю ширину и при этом прижать его кверху в QT Designer?
У меня есть контейнер, в который я хочу всунуть форму, при этом хочу чтобы она растягивалась на всю длину этого контейнера и при этом была прижата кверху.
Можно просто разместить форму по координатам и тогда она будет прижата кверху, как мне надо, но в таком случае, она не будет растянута на всю ширину.

Также можно у родительского элемента выбрать layout, в таком случае нужная мне форма растянется на всю ширину, но при этом она не будет прижата кверху.

Я пробовал выставлять в стиль формы width: 100%, но видимо я что-то не так понимаю и это здесь не работает.
В планах далее реализовать следующие функции: возможность в программе добавлять новые формы, в которые будут вставляться текстовые блоки. Блоки соответственно тоже должны быть растянуты на всю ширину формы и прижаты кверху. При этом высота блока текста должна меняться в зависимости от ширины внешней формы.
Надеюсь смог понятно объяснить свою идею :) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это реализовать? Можно ли это вообще реализовать через QT Designer или единственный вариант - это в уже в коде создавать событие "изменение размеров окна" и привязывать к этому событию изменение размеров формы и блоков текста внутри?
П.С. Структура программы:

П.П.С. файл .ui
https://fex.net/ru/s/bzrcddc

Леонид Бабкин, добавьте модуль .ui, результаты которого показаны на втором изображении и еще раз уточните, что вы хотите сделать в текущий момент, без каких-либо планов на то. что вы в дальнейшем собираетесь реализовать.

@S.Nick файл добавил в конец вопроса. Ещё раз что нужно сделать:
мне нужно, чтобы divide_frame растягивалась на всю ширину своего контейнера (Scroll Area) и при этом была прижата кверху этого самого контейнера.
